# Using cheerio to scrape data from links extracted using cheerio

Tags: node.js, api, web-scraping, cheerio

Are using cheerio and nodejs to get data from the allegro website to create endpoints in an API that gives back csv data this data will be studied later on as part of a data science project:

https://allegro.pl/kategoria/samochody-osobowe-4029?bmatch=baseline-al-product-cl-eyesa2-engag-dict45-aut-1-3-0605

to get the cars information I managed to scrape off the links from the first page each link sends you to the car (item of cars) to see the full information of the car I need to scrape more data from each link how do I do that?

and how to i make the json data shows off as csv instead ?

here the code used :

```
const url =
  "https://allegro.pl/kategoria/samochody-osobowe-4029?bmatch=baseline-al-product-cl-eyesa2-engag-dict45-aut-1-3-0605";

//const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("allegro.csv");
// Write Headers
//writeStream.write(`Price,Link \n`);

function getCars() {
  return fetch(`${url}`)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((body) => {
      const cars = [];
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      $("._9c44d_2H7Kt").each(function (i, el) {
        const $price = $(el).find("._9c44d_1zemI");
        const $link = $(el).find("a");
        const $year = $(el).find("dd");
        const $make = $(el).find("h2");

        const car = {
          price: $price.text().replace(/\s\s+/g, ""),
          link: $link.attr("href"),
          year: $year.first().next().next().text(),
          make: $make.text(),
        };
        cars.push(car);
      });

      // Write Row to CSV
      // writeStream.write(`${price},${link} \n`);
      return cars;
    });
}
```

the code used for the nodejs endpoint :

```
app.get("/scraping/:allegro", (req, res) => {
  scraper.getCars(req.param.allegro).then((cars) => {
    //console.log(cars);
    res.json(cars);
  });
```

The data to get from each link is the following : date added,model,phone number, city,vin

Answer (score 1):

There is a convenient thing about these pages, it's that you can return the data in JSON instead of html by just setting the media type to `application/json` eg setting the `Accept` header.

For instance to get the list :

```
curl "https://allegro.pl/kategoria/samochody-osobowe-4029?bmatch=baseline-al-product-cl-eyesa2-engag-dict45-aut-1-3-0605&order=dd" \
     -H "Accept: application/json"
```

To get a specific item :

```
curl "https://allegro.pl/ogloszenie/mercedes-ml320-9341716141" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

So you don't need to use webscraping tools just parsing JSON. The pagination is done by adding a query param `&p=PAGE_NUM` which is convenient too

I've made a small example in [python](/questions/tagged/python) that can be easily ported to JS. It request the list of cars, then request the first element :

```python
import requests 
import json
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://allegro.pl/kategoria/samochody-osobowe-4029",
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    params = {
        "bmatch":"baseline-al-product-cl-eyesa2-engag-dict45-aut-1-3-0605",
        "order":"dd"
    })
data = [{
        "name": t["name"],
        "url": t["url"],
        "price": t["sellingMode"]["advertisement"]["price"]["amount"],
        **dict([(j["name"],j["values"][0]) for j in t["parameters"]]),
    }
    for t in r.json()["pagination bottom"]["collection"]["items"]["promoted"]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

print("get data for first element")
r = requests.get(data[0]["url"],
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json"
    })
item = r.json()
item_data = {
    "phone": item["summary"]["offer"]["contact"]["phones"][0]["number"],
    "delivery": item["summary"]["offer"]["delivery"]["summary"][0]["value"]["text"],
    "startingAt": item["summary"]["offer"]["publication"]["startingAt"],
    "endingAt": item["summary"]["offer"]["publication"]["endingAt"],
    **dict([(j["name"], j["values"][0]["valueLabel"]) for j in item["summary"]["offer"]["parametersGroups"]["groups"][0]["parameters"]])
}

print(item_data)
```

An implementation in [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) using axios :

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function process() {
    let response = await axios.get('https://allegro.pl/kategoria/samochody-osobowe-4029',{
        query: {
            "bmatch":"baseline-al-product-cl-eyesa2-engag-dict45-aut-1-3-0605",
            "order":"dd"
        },
        responseType: "json"
    });
    let promoted = response.data["pagination bottom"].collection.items.promoted;
    list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < promoted.length;i++) {
        let item = {
            name: promoted[i].name,
            url: promoted[i].url,
            price: promoted[i].sellingMode.advertisement.price.amount,
        };
        let params = promoted[i].parameters;
        for (var j = 0; j < params.length;j++){
            item[params[j].name] = params[j].values[0];
        }
        list.push(item);
    }
    console.log(list);
    console.log("fetching : " + list[0].url);
    response = await axios.get(list[0].url,{
        responseType: "json"
    });
    let entryData = response.data;
    let entry = {
        phone: entryData.summary.offer.contact.phones[0].number,
        delivery: entryData.summary.offer.delivery.summary[0].value.text,
        startingAt: entryData.summary.offer.publication.startingAt,
        endingAt: entryData.summary.offer.publication.endingAt
    };
    let parameters = entryData.summary.offer.parametersGroups.groups[0].parameters;
    for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length;i++) {
        entry[parameters[i].name] = parameters[i].values[0].valueLabel
    }
    console.log(entry);
}

process();
```

Comment: thank you so much for your very detailed anwser it was a huge help my question is there a way to make this python file runs automaticly everytime and adds on new scraped data to the previously scraped that is that something that can be done?

Comment: It depends on the site, I can’t read polish but if you can sort by most recent the entries (some filter on the page?) you can use that new query parameter (if existing) in your script. You would store everything in database with the entry id (from the json). When your script run it would store the entries in database until it finds an existing id

Comment: i see thank you for response , only problem i have now is how do i go along with connecting pythong to nodejs and express so i create endpoints to acess data from the browser before using cheerio i only exported the modules to use them

Comment: @Souhaildq I've added an implementation in nodejs. Note that I use the `promoted` field here to extract list data but maybe there are other fields holding items, I didn't look much at other fields

Comment: thank you so much you are a life saver , do i need to save the data to a data base to be able to acess it from endpoints?

Comment: not necessarily you could send as json using `r.json(entry)` like `function(req,res) {  //fetch data here  res.json(entry); }`. But if you want to download file, maybe you would need to create a temporary file before streaming it

Comment: I tried saving it to the data base using `var mongo = require("mongodb");
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/scraping", {
  native_parser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});` and ` db.collection("allegro").insert(entry, function (error, record) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log("entries saved");
  });` and for some reason i get nothing saved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215587/discussion-between-souhaildq-and-bertrand-martel).